# where to store JWT token Laravel 5.6 Apps?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, jwt

Currently, I build a web app using `laravel 5.6` which has web and API route inside that, and I used `JWT token` as authentication for APIs.

I just want to know which is more secure or most secure way to store `JWT token`?

In `Laravel` session or `JavaScript localStorage`?

Comment: Laravel session.

Comment: JWT is stateless so it should not be in server. store it to browser storage

Comment: is localstorage vulnerable to XSS attack?

Answer (score 1):

Json web token works on stateless. So please don't store on Laravel session. You can use local storage or web cookies.
For more info please refer here [Thread](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all answers, finally i ended up using cookies to store and get the token. because i'm using laravel too as my front end and no need to pass token in authorization header, and another benefit using laravel cookies is secure because all value in the cookies is encrypted, if user hijacked the cookies it will be invalid. :D